# The probability of get largest number by comparing previous samples.

Tags: probability

Suppose we had balls numbered $1,2,3,...,N$ in a bag. We draw the balls without replacement for $i$ times. If in the ball of $i$th draw has number larger than the balls in $1,2,3,....,i-1$ th draw, then the ball is chosen. What is the probability the ball with number $S$ is chosen in the $i$th draw?

Two cases are consisdered.

1. We just draw $i$ time. The drawing stops at exactly $i$th draw.
2. We kept drawing if the $i$th ball is not largest so far, it was discarded and we continue to draw. If in the $j$th draw ( where $i<j \leq N$) the ball is largest so far, the ball is chosen and the drawing sequence stops. If there is no ball matches the criteria, we kep drawing up to $N$ times without any ball left in the bag.

I believe this kind of problem is with practical use and must had been modeled well. May anyone help me to find reference with a thorough exploaration of this kind of problem? Of course just an answer of this problem is welcomed.

Comment: What happens if the $i$th ball isn't the largest so far?

Comment: @paw88789 I want to discuss two cases: 1. we just do $i$ times of draw and stop.  2. we keep drawing until we had the largest number so far in j th draw. If there is no draw with a largest number so far, we draw $N$ times and stop without any ball left in the bag. I think the first case can extend to the second case.

Comment: Please edit the post for clarity, as it stands the rules are not clear.  If you are thinking about multiple variants of the rule set, that's fine, but each variant should be clearly described in the post itself.

Comment: I apologize for not making it clearly. I am editing the post now.

Comment: As a general remark...if you have $i$ distinct numbers, the probability that any one of them is the largest is $\frac 1i$.  Depending on your rule set, this is relevant.

Comment: I see the edit, but it still isn't clear.  What happens to the ball if it is not chosen?  Is it replaced or is it discarded?

Comment: @lulu It will be discarded. All drawing is without replacement.

Comment: In that case, the posted hint below seems spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

For Ball $S$ to be chosen in the $i$th draw, you need

- the first $i-1$ balls to have numbers strictly below $S$
- followed by $S$ being drawn in the $i$th draw

These are not independent events, so I would suggest calculating the second probability conditioned on the first being true. Then multiply

If you want to be able to continue the draw to see whether Ball $S$ is chosen on any of the $i$th, $i+1$th, $\ldots$, $n$th draws, it gets much more complicated.  You need

Comment: Here is my thinking process following this hint: There are $S-1$ number strictly below $S$. The the probability of first $i-1$ ball have numbers strictly below $S$ is $ \frac {(S-1)(S-2)...(S-i+1)}{N(N-1)...(N-i+2)}$. The probability of $S$ in $i$th draw given there are $i-1$ balls have been drawn is $\frac {1}{N-i+1} $. Therefore the answwer in case one is the product of them. However when I test the special case $S=N$ the product become $\frac{1}{N}$ which is independent of $i$. I must make a mistake but I do not know where the mistake is.

Comment: In the case $S=N$ then $\frac1N$ is indeed correct for the first part of your question.